# How to exit from a function in c# without closing PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell

I am using Powershell as my Console. I created a PSSnapin and added it to Powershell. Now i want that for some exception, it should exit there, but since i have called it from some function, it returns back there which i don't want. I want it to exit at that instant only without closing the powershell Console. I tried Environment.Exit(0) but it is closing the console application. Is there any other way to exit?

Comment: What happens if you call `Dispose` on your snapin instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snapins run in the PowerShell process and as such, PowerShell attempts to protect itself by catching exceptions that a snapin throws.  The last thing you want to do is call `Environment.Exit()` because that will kill the PowerShell process.  You can either let the exception escape from your cmdlet implementation (or throw if necessary) but it would be better to use the `ThrowTerminatingError()` method on your PSCmdlet instance to signal a terminating condition for your cmdlet.